# yii cgridview tooltip php variable

Tags: yii, tooltip, cgridview

This is my one of the Cgridview Column

```
  array(        'name'=>'furnished',
                'type'=>'raw',
                'value'=>'$data->furnished=="FF" ? CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->furnished),
                "tooltip",["title"=>"**Here I Want to show <?php echo $data->anystring ?>**", "data-toggle"=>"tooltip",
                        "style"=>"text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;"]) : $data->furnished',       
        ),
```

How can I achieve this . Please help

normally typed data is displayed here. but how to show PHP variable

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 0):

Everything in `value` will be executed via `PHP`'s `eval()` function. So you must change your code to this:

```
'value'=>'$data->furnished=="FF" ? CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->furnished),
    "tooltip",["title"=>"**Here I Want to show ".$data->anystring."**", "data-toggle"=>"tooltip",
    "style"=>"text-decoration: none; cursor:pointer;"]) : $data->furnished'
```

Actually, you don't need `<?php` and all you need is just `.`.

Comment: Thank you. I have used this only in title::  Workstations:$data->workstations, Reception:$data->reception . But I want to check if $data->workstations!="" then only show workstation. for that I make call to one Model function. bt its not working. :(

Comment: I want to call function how can I achieve??